# How to support or render or view HEIF Image format?

Tags: android, heif

I captured a photo using camera on android device. Camera app used is the default camera app that is shipped with the Stock Android. I want to compress `.jpeg` images to `.heic` file format on android platform. User should be able to view the same on android platform.

Answer (score 2):

Try this library, maybe it would help: [Heif Reader](https://github.com/yohhoy/heifreader)

```
HeifReader.initialize(this);

// decode Bitmap from HEIF raw resource
Bitmap bmp = HeifReader.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.raw.heif_data);
// draw Bitmap on ViewImage
imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) can be used to view HEIF [Glide source code comment](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/blob/a3a3a6573addd83a5be031bbd55d29e7514ca446/library/src/main/java/com/bumptech/glide/Glide.java#L403)